# GridView shows an Image crop when using custom adapter with long text

Tags: android, gridview, android-custom-view, custom-adapter

`public class CategoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context context;
ViewHolder holder;
private ArrayList<String> categoryNamesList, categoryIdList;
private final static int selectorsArray[] = { R.drawable.telecom_seletor, R.drawable.airlines_seletor, R.drawable.banking_seletor, R.drawable.dth_selector, R.drawable.electronics_seletor, R.drawable.health_seletor, R.drawable.holidays_seletor, R.drawable.insurance_seletor, R.drawable.shopping_web_seletor, R.drawable.taxi_seletor, R.drawable.food_seletor };

public CategoryListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> categoryNamesList, ArrayList<String> categoryIdList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.categoryNamesList = categoryNamesList;
    this.categoryIdList = categoryIdList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return categoryNamesList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return categoryNamesList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_title);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.title.setText(categoryNamesList.get(position));
    holder.icon.setBackgroundResource(selectorsArray[position % selectorsArray.length]);
    return convertView;
}
```

}
`i use image as icons and text as their labels but when i use text with long length and scroll down and then up the image icon will get cropped.
Any suggession guys. Plz help.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_2CFh5suxS4bm83OVFqNHRLa1U/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_2CFh5suxS4MHdJVktMVkpwXzg/view?usp=sharing

Link for the issue image

Comment: explain your issue with code snippet what you have done

Comment: just a minute please....i will add a screenshot..

Answer (score 0):

getView in your BaseAdapter class should be like this:
    `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_custom_grid, null);
        } else
            grid = (View) convertView;`

and try `imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);`